# Books or sources to find basic math explanations (like the one for the question below (matrix multiplication))

Tags: reference-request

i have a huge problem in understanding math. Not that huge, but i miss lots of basic concepts and have lots of questions that i've never been taught at school/university.

For example: Multiplication between matrices.
We have matrix A and matrix B. I want to find A x B.
Why do we have to SUM the elements of the column B multiplied by the elements of the row A to have one element of the AB matrix?
Why can't we just multiply element by element?

Another example: what is a permutation and WHY do we have to do operations between them and why these operations (like the composition operation) are like the way they are?

Teachers use to give you the formula, the scheme of the "matrix", "permutation" or whatever and then let you solve the exercises without letting you (me at least) understand what you are really doing with these numbers.

The answers may be simple or not, but i really need to understand these basic things and if some of you knows any good book that explains these and other things that would be great!

I hope i've been understood, because i'm not native English and i'm not used to speak with "technical" or mathematical terms.

Comment: Why not ask your teacher? Also, how old are you and how much do you know about linear algebra?

Comment: For any math subject you want to learn, you can usually find threads on math.stackexchange that discuss the best books for that subject.

Comment: "why not ask your teacher?" is a poor question. Let's close this website then, because "why not ask your teacher?" can be an answer to every question?

Comment: @littleO the fact is that i haven't found yet a book that explains the things the way that i want. I'll check in the meanwhile, thanks